# Java webapp how to publish its DNS name in intranet

Tags: java, dns, netbios

I have a Tomcat server with a Java Spring webapp installed in a Windows machine. This is an intranet application and I would like to publish in the local network the name of this host, for example using NetBios name.
Is there any way to do this with Java?

My goal is to reach this service with the app name to every browser in the network with:
**http://myapp**
This should work also if this application server is using DHCP and its address changes.
This application is not published in a network with its own dns server.

For now I had to change all file hosts of every client in the network and I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: Since you're operating in an intranet (and assuming that this is a company network) why aren't you asking for your sysadmin to create a DNS entry for the application's domain?

Comment: You could look at https://www.noip.com/free for dynamic dns

Comment: @mdeora this is not a DDNS problem, I need to publish the local-network ip inside my network. I have this problem because there is not a DNS local server.

Comment: In that case I would recommend to use a DNS server in your LAN. That would be the most easy, I guess.